# run multiple model and save model comparison results in dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to run lm models and save model comparison result and extract p-values. I would like to save all the info in a dataframe.
Using diamonds dataset as an example:

```
    diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut) %>% 
    do(model1 = lm(price~carat, data=.),
       model2 = lm(price~carat+depth, data=.)) %>% 
    mutate(anova = anova(model2,model1)) %>% 
    mutate(pval= anova$'Pr(>F'[2])
```

I got error message below:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `anova` must be length 1 (the group size), not 6
```

My question is:

1. Why I got the error message and how to save anova result in the dataframe?
2. how to make the whole process work if lm or anova do not work on some subsets?  something like try..catch..

My real data is more complicated then this. Just use diamonds and linear model to illustrate the idea. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Objects of class `anova` inherit from class `data.frame`. They have 6 columns and since dfs are special cases of objects of class `list`, the value of `length(anova(m1, m2))` is 6.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas   Thanks. So how can I save the anova result in the dataframe, like other model results?

Comment: You can have a data frame column hold any kind of object, including objects of class `data.frame`. But do you really need it all? You would be, for instance, duplicating the `F` statistic since you also keep `'Pr(>F)'[2]` (there's a typo in your code, btw). I believe that you should save the `anova` results in a list, not in the original data frame `diamonds`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a really good application of the `tidyr::nest()` function in conjunction with `purrr` and `broom`. What you do is: 
- Group the data frame
- Apply a model with `mutate(mod = map(data, model)` 
- summarize the model using `broom::tidy()` 
- extract the relevant statistics.

For more on this here's a great talk by Hadley on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg

In your case I think you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
diamonds %>% 
        group_by(cut) %>% 
           nest() %>% 
           mutate(
               model1 = map(data, ~lm(price~carat, data=.)),
               model2 = map(data, ~lm(price~carat+depth, data=.))
           ) %>% 
           mutate(anova = map2(model1, model2, ~anova(.x,.y))) %>% 
        mutate(tidy_anova = map(anova, broom::tidy)) %>% 
        mutate(p_val = map_dbl(tidy_anova, ~.$p.value[2])) %>%
        select(p_val)
```